# what does "error : a nonstatic member reference must be relative to a specific object" mean?

Tags: c++, dll, compiler-errors, member-functions

```
int CPMSifDlg::EncodeAndSend(char *firstName, char *lastName, char *roomNumber, char *userId, char *userFirstName, char *userLastName)
{
    ...

    return 1;
}

extern "C"
{
    __declspec(dllexport) int start(char *firstName, char *lastName, char *roomNumber, char *userId, char *userFirstName, char *userLastName)
    {
        return CPMSifDlg::EncodeAndSend(firstName, lastName, roomNumber, userId, userFirstName, userLastName);
    }
}
```

On line `return CPMSifDlg::EncodeAndSend` I have an error :
Error : a nonstatic member reference must be relative to a specific object.

What does it mean?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

`EncodeAndSend` is not a static function, which means it can be called on an instance of the class `CPMSifDlg`. You cannot write this:

```
 CPMSifDlg::EncodeAndSend(/*...*/);  //wrong - EncodeAndSend is not static
```

It should rather be called as:

```
 CPMSifDlg dlg; //create instance, assuming it has default constructor!
 dlg.EncodeAndSend(/*...*/);   //correct
```

Comment: but if i remove the "CPMSifDlg", i got "error : identifier EncodeAndSend is undefined"

Comment: like this right?

`CPMSifDlg dlg;
  return dlg.EncodeAndSend(firstName, lastName, roomNumber, userId, userFirstName, userLastName);`

it says the method is inaccessible

Comment: @OscarYuandinata: Yes. You need to create an instance of the class, in order to call the function. Or, make the function a static member function, or simply a free function.

Comment: like this right? `CPMSifDlg dlg; return dlg.EncodeAndSend(firstName, lastName, roomNumber, userId, userFirstName, userLastName);` it says the method is inaccessible

Comment: the question is, if they are friend classes, it will still have this error, which does not make any sense. strange

Answer (score 15):

Only static functions are called with class name.

```
classname::Staicfunction();
```

Non static functions have to be called using objects.

```
classname obj;
obj.Somefunction();
```

This is exactly what your error means. Since your function is non static you have to use a object reference to invoke it.

Comment: I don't think this is strictly true. If calling a non-static method in a base class from inside a derived class then the syntax Base::function() is used.

Comment: if your method in derived is non static.

Answer (score 12):

`CPMSifDlg::EncodeAndSend()` method is declared as non-`static` and thus it must be called using an object of `CPMSifDlg`. e.g.

```
CPMSifDlg obj;
return obj.EncodeAndSend(firstName, lastName, roomNumber, userId, userFirstName, userLastName);
```

If `EncodeAndSend` doesn't use/relate any specifics of an object (i.e. `this`) but general for the `class CPMSifDlg` then declare it as `static`:

```
class CPMSifDlg {
...
  static int EncodeAndSend(...);
  ^^^^^^
};
```