# C++: a nonstatic member reference must be relative to a specific object

Tags: c++, arrays, error-handling, compiler-errors, member

I've seen a number of posts on this but they all seem to be addressing when spme sort of method is defined.

Background for app: Just trying to make a basic Sudoku game to get the hang of C++.

The error seems independent of the main function .cpp file, so I'll ignore it unless it's requested to keep the explanation short.

The board.h file:

```
#pragma once
class board
{
public:
    board(int gameSize, int diffifuclty) : gameSize(gameSize), difficulty(difficulty) {};
    ~board();

private:
    int gameSize; int difficulty;
    int game[gameSize][gameSize][gameSize][gameSize];
    void createRandom(); // Creates a random workable board.
    void hasSolution(); // Checks if there's a solution from the current state.

};
```

I haven't toyed much with the board.cpp file yet, as I  was just busy defining everything in the board.h file to plan out what functions I want to write.

Anyways, I want to have a game board with `gameSize` and `difficulty` being inputted in the console. I'm getting the error mentioned in my title when I try to construct the multidimensional array for the game board. (So with Sudoku, the 9x9 game has game size 3 here.)

I'm not sure what the error is or how to make this array an attribute (I'm not sure if this is C++ terminology, so sorry) of board?

Comment: Your array cannot use member variables for the size.  they must be available at compile time.  So either use a vector<vector<vector<vector<int>>>> or use a vector of gamesize^4 with a translation function, use a int**** or pass it as a template parameter.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you have is a typical OOP problem with C++. You can find more explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9818515/what-does-error-a-nonstatic-member-reference-must-be-relative-to-a-specific-o) .

It is because you did not create an object first before you refer to any member of the class.

For example,

```
construct(game); // game is a member of class board. you need to create an object of board first.
```

Here is the correct one

```
board bd;
construct(bd.game);
```

Comment: Ok so this is where I get confused,  as I'm guessing C++ is different than other languages in this aspect. First off, does this code go into my `main`, board.h file, or board.cpp file? Second, how do I make a multidimensional array as required in my class then? In other languages, doing something similar wouldn't give me a problem, as I'm just using an attribute. So what's different here?

Comment: as far as I know, Java, C#, etc have the same concept regarding `static`. C++ is not different from them.  normally board.cpp is the implementation of class board. the instantiation of board class is done somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

**First** in C++, the size of an array must be a **compile-time constant**.So,  take for example the following code snippets:

```
int n = 10;
int arr[n]; //INCORRECT because n is not a constant expression
```

The correct way to write the above would be:

```
const int n = 10;
int arr[n]; //CORRECT
```

Similarly, the following(which you did in your code example) is incorrect:

```
 int gameSize; int difficulty;
 int game[gameSize][gameSize][gameSize][gameSize];//INCORRECT because gameSize isn't a constant expression
```

#### Solution

To solve this you can use a **3D`std::vector`** and initialize it using a **constructor initializer list** as shown below:

```
#pragma once
#include <vector>
class board
{
public:
    //USE THE CONSTRUCTOR INITIALIZER LIST
    board(int gameSize, int diffifuclty) : gameSize(gameSize), 
                                           difficulty(difficulty), 
                                           game(gameSize, std::vector<std::vector<int>>(gameSize, std::vector<int>(gameSize))) {};
    ~board();

private:
    int gameSize; int difficulty;
    
    //a 3D vector instead of built in array
    std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<int>>> game;
    
    void createRandom();
    void hasSolution(); 

};
```